# Is Vim's filename completion broken in Windows when using uppercase u umlaute (Ü)?

Tags: microsoft-windows, unicode

In a vim buffer, I want to insert the path to a file named `blablabla\barbar-Überbar\bazbazbaz.txt` which exists under the current working directory - and I am running gvim in a MS-Windows environment.

So I type `ibla` (to insert `bla` in the buffer) then `ctrl-x ctrl-f`. Vim expands to `blablabla\`. I further type `bar` and then `ctrl-x ctrl-f`. Vim expands to `foofoofoo\barbar-Überbar\`. I type `baz` (so the text reads `foofoofoo\barbar-Überbar\baz` and the cursor is immediatly after `baz`) and use `ctrl-x ctrl-f` again. This time, vim won't expand the path as expected.

If, however, the path contains a lowercase `ü` instead of the uppercase cousin, it will expand as expected.

So, I assume that support for the uppercase U Umlaut is broken.

Can someone verify my assumption?

Edit: BTW, on Linux, it seems to work fine.

**Edit II**

Ok, my vimrc sets `encoding` to `utf8`. If I change the encoding to `latin1` the whole completion mechanism seems to work.

*However*, I cannot change the encoding to `latin1` as I have many utf-8 files I am editing, and they are then displayed very wierdly.

Comment: have you looked here http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Opening-files-with-Unicode-names-under-Windows-td1207885.html

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but the nabble link only restated the problem. Some solutions given there didn't work for me.